# Upvoted answers counted as accepted in Android app's question list

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, accepted-answer, question-lists

So I'm scrolling through questions, and I see this:

> [image]

Oh, goodie, there's an accepted answer here!

> [image]

Or not.

---

Is the background supposed to be green for any question having an upvoted answer? It seems that it is meant to show whether the question has an accepted answer, like it does on the site.

I've also noticed that 0-score accepted answers don't cause the background to be green. It's based purely on whether there's an upvoted answer.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the rules that @Kasra has stated in his answer.  Those are the rules the site uses.  However, one thing we've tried is having the green bubble icon itself have the same three states.

[image: Whoops! A pre-alpha iOS screenshot leak!]

It could be the unfilled green bubble is less suggestive of an accepted answer than a filled one.

Comment: Now you're just teasing them... I do like the non-filled in answer icon, however I don't know how obvious its intent would be to someone seeing it without seeing the filled in and gray states right next to it.

Comment: Personally I like the three states the hollow grey answer icon for no answers, hollow green answer icon for an answer and solid for an accepted answer. Problem is in the app they are not working like that, especially showing the green background when an answer is accepted, that shows at the moment when an answer is voted up regardless of its accepted state.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2/26**: There was an issue with the three states the application had, where state #2 was never actually used correctly. This has now been fixed, and the Android application 
now follows the same rules as the website and the iOS application.

---

This is really confusing and we've talked about it a lot internally.

The app currently has *three* states, same as the websites. Here are what they are for the app:

- No answers: Gray answer count, gray answer icon, no background on answer/votes (left side)
- At least one answer: Green answer count, green answer icon, no background on answer/votes (left side)
- Accepted answer: Green answer count, green answer icon, green background color on left side of row.

This matches the websites three states. Using Stack Overflow as the example:

- No answer: no special indication
- At least one answer: Green background box around answer count.
- Accepted answer: Green background box, green text.

Personally, I'd prefer to have the app only have green icon and text if there's an accepted answer (alongside the green background) else even if there are no answers or at least one (but unaccepted) answer it's simply show them in gray. Let me know if you have any suggestions for a less confusing way to deal with it instead.

Comment: But the app doesn't use that second state properly! It uses it for questions that have answers, all of which _are 0 or lower_. As soon as one answer gets an upvote it switches to state 3. _That's_ the issue.

Comment: Kasra? Did you get a chance to read my comment above? (Sorry to bother you)

Comment: @HodofHod I did not, but I'll take a look in the morning. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: @HodofHod this has been fixed, I don't know as of when but I'm not seeing any questions without accepted answers with state 3 now.

Comment: Assuming that I'm understanding correctly that only questions with _accepted_ answers should show the green background on their vote counts, I'm still seeing this. Green background: http://i.stack.imgur.com/al9Wp.png and no accepted answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bX93P.png

Comment: @HodOfHod You are very correct. Sorry about that, *now* it's actually been fixed (as of next release)

Comment: Thanks! (I have to be honest, at one point I was scratching my head wondering if I was crazy :D) What's the behavior now for questions with only 0-score answers? (Previously it was state 2)

Comment: Do we know when the next release is find the current states very confusing?

Comment: @Lankymart A new release went out about 30 minutes ago meaning it should hit all devices in the next hour or two.

Comment: @KasraRahierdi Just updated the app and still the states are wrong, some show with solid green answer icon and green background when they don't have an accepted answer. It's like HodOfHod said they seem to be questions with upvoted answers.

Comment: @KasraRahierdi Apologies after clearing my cache it is working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: I've got the new version and everything looks ok. Do you want to mark this as completed, and maybe add or edit your answer as per our discussion?

Comment: I've notice there still seems to be an issue, although the icons display correctly now the green background is hit and miss. Appears to only show if accepted answer has been voted up. Anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi This is still an issue in the app, is there any update on this? If an answer is upvoted the background still turns green on the feed list even though it is not accepted. Anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Here is a [convo we had in the tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/android-app-upvote-showing-as-accepted-in-feed) about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mobile users only care if a question is answered, not if it has an accepted answer or not.

Comment: There is no distinction between 2 and 3 in the android app.

Comment: Huh.  Well, to be honest, I rarely need to distinguish the two when deciding if I want to look at a question.  Perhaps they didn't see it as useful to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: Right. That's why I asked if it was intended.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the states are there just not being distinguished correctly.