# Android app indicates that a question has accepted answer on search result, when it has not

Tags: bug, search, android-app, accepted-answer

> [image: green color, indicator of having accepted answer]

As you can see above, when I searched [my question on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233232), it's solid green (accepted answer indicator), but I haven't accepted any answer.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Spreadtrum
- Device Model: Celkon A35K

  - OS Version: 4.4.2 (eng.root.20140613.225402)

Comment: Repro'd, and AFAIK, it only happens on search result. Seems related to "answered question" (has an accepted answer *or* answers with positive score), but not sure why.

Comment: @AndrewT. What is AFAIK and Repro'd?

Comment: Sorry, "repro'd" is "reproduced", which means "I can observe this on my device". "AFAIK" is "As Far As I Know".

Comment: Related: [Upvoted answers counted as accepted in app's results list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195019/upvoted-answers-counted-as-accepted-in-apps-results-list?rq=1) (but this is on main question list which has been fixed in 2014)

Comment: Why had I received a down vote? I know this don't much but  Is reporting a minor bug wrong?

Comment: I think because it's unclear when you posted the original revision of this post, as indicated by wrong answer that had been deleted. Don't mind it, it's an okay bug report.

Comment: I searched for another question today, it showed no answer marked when answer was already accepted.